# Fill DropdownButton with read data from sqlite with drift package in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have DropdownButton in flutter like here:

```
            import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
            import 'package:softshop/DataBase_Layer/app_db.dart';

            /// Flutter code sample for [DropdownButton].

            class MyDropDown extends StatefulWidget {
              const MyDropDown({super.key});

              @override
              State<MyDropDown> createState() => _MyDropDownState();
            }

            class _MyDropDownState extends State<MyDropDown> {
              String dropdownValue = '';
              late AppDb _db;

              @override
              void initState() {
                super.initState();

                _db = AppDb();

                // Get the categories from the database.
                _db.getCategories().then((categories) {
                  setState(() {
                    dropdownValue = categories.first.nomecategoria;
                  });
                });
              }

              @override
              Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                Future<List<CategoriaData>> list = _db.getCategories();

                list.then((categories) {
                  return DecoratedBox(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                    child: DropdownButton<String>(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                      isExpanded: true,
                      value: dropdownValue,
                      iconSize: 50,
                      elevation: 16,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      onChanged: (String? value) {
                        // This is called when the user selects an item.
                        setState(() {
                          dropdownValue = value!;
                        });
                      },
                      items: categories
                          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((CategoriaData categoria) {
                        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                          value: categoria.nomecategoria,
                          child: Text(categoria.nomecategoria),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    ),
                  );
                });

                return Container();
              }
            }
```

and I am using drift pakcage to read data from sqlite database like here:

```
                import 'dart:io';

            import 'package:drift/drift.dart';
            import 'package:drift/native.dart';
            import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
            import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;
            import 'package:softshop/DataBase_Layer/Entity/categoria_Entity.dart';
            import 'package:softshop/DataBase_Layer/Entity/prodotto_Entity.dart';

            part 'app_db.g.dart';

            //for create db use this syntax: flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

            LazyDatabase _openconnection() {
              return LazyDatabase(() async {
                final dbfolder = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
                final file = File(path.join(dbfolder.path, 'database.db'));

                return NativeDatabase(file);
              });
            }

            @DriftDatabase(tables: [Categoria, Prodotto])
            class AppDb extends _$AppDb {
              AppDb() : super(_openconnection());

              @override
              int get schemaVersion => 1;

              //List of Categoria
              Future<List<CategoriaData>> getCategories() async {
                return await select(categoria).get();
              }

              Future<CategoriaData> getCategoria(int id) async {
                return await (select(categoria)..where((tbl) => tbl.idcategorie.equals(id)))
                    .getSingle();
              }

              Future<bool> updateCategoria(CategoriaCompanion entity) async {
                return await update(categoria).replace(entity);
              }

              Future<int> insertCategoria(CategoriaCompanion entity) async {
                return await into(categoria).insert(entity);
              }

              Future<int> deleteCategoria(int id) async {
                return await (delete(categoria)..where((tbl) => tbl.idcategorie.equals(id)))
                    .go();
              }
            }
```

i dont have any error but my code does not work! how could i read data from sqlite database and set data inside DropdownButton??
as you see in code i am using getCategories() method to read data from database.